# What is the logical definition of a google api project

Tags: google-api

I am confused about the features, functionality, and boundaries of a Google API project. A single Google API project can have many credentials.

If your apps will all be using the same APIs, why would you want to create separate projects?

When or under what conditions should you create additional credentials fo the same project?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Base on Google Doc: Before you can send requests to Google Apps Activity API, you need to tell Google about your client and activate access to the API. You do this by using the Google Developers Console to create a project, which is a named collection of settings and API access information.

As above, Each API project is a named collection of settings and API access information. You can read [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/v1/guides/project)

Comment: For some unknown reason, Google does a terrible job explaining what the different parts of the API are used for. I've been trying to figure it out for months, on and off, and still have no idea. Google tells you the buttons to click to generate things, but not why you need each thing. It almost seems like they think they automated it to the point where you do exactly what they say, and don't need to worry about what the code does or why, but as programmers, we need to understand how things work, so all that does is annoy me. This explanation doesn't clarify anything - neither does the link.